# 'BackgroundModes' - system capability is not listing inside the 'project.pbxproj' file of an iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to integrate the `Background fetch` feature inside a Flutter project using Workmanager plugin. So I enabled the `background fetch` feature under 'Background Modes' of my iOS project Capability.
But the following block is not added to `project.pbxproj` file. As I understood, it should be automatically added by XCode.

```
SystemCapabilities = {
                            com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
                                enabled = 1;
                            };
                        };
```

Currently, I am working with Xcode 11.3.1 and Swift 5.0.  So how do I bring the above snippet in project.pbxproj file?. Or please help me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: did you solve this?